# Need help in Regex for a specific ID

Tags: javascript, regex

My web application wanted to validate CompanyID for

> Anthony o'Donoghue/UK/XYZ

format using regex.

Company ID should have person name, followed by  forward slash, then country name/code followed by forward slash, then company name.

Person name can have special character like **'**

I was trying to validate using javascript by

```
if (!(/\//g.test(CompanyID))) 
        {
        alert('\tInvalid Company ID.\n\tPlease type in "personName/country/company" format');
        return false;
        }
```

What changes should I make?

Comment: Not my downvote, but your question sort of has a "do you haz the codez" flavor to it.  A single regex might not be enough for you to validate, because there are hundreds of country codes.

Comment: More than just `[^/]+\/[^/]+\/[^/]+`?  PS, a regex is the not the right hammer for every screw.  Also you may find online regex testers like https://www.regextester.com/ helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps that helps:

```
/^[\w '´`]+?\/[A-Z]{2}\/[\w '´`]+$/
```

See here: https://regex101.com/r/fR1QVY/2

If you need to match other signs than (A-Z a-z _ Space ' `´) as well for person names or company names, you have to add the signs in [\w '´`]

Comment: If it was helpful, it would be great it you vote it up. Thanks. :-)

Comment: I did it yesterday itself, but it is not showing up, as I dont have sufficient reputation.